# aiohttp middleware and updating the url for a request

Tags: python, middleware, aiohttp

I am looking for help with an aiohttp middleware I'm working on that will automatically add trailing slashes to a uri if it's missing. Aiohttp requires that when you define a url, you define two routes for each path in your list of routes, one with a trailing slash and one without. They have an example middleware that addresses this by finding if the uri does not end with a `/` and adding it if not, but then they use an http 302 redirect to tell the client to go to the new uri. Otherwise a relative uri like `/endpoint` will 404 while `/endpoint/` will work.

This is their middleware:
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/web_middlewares.py

Using their middleware as a basis, I'm trying to accomplish the same thing but without a redirect on the client side. I want the handling to only be on the server. My current attempt at this is shown below and seems to update the request in flight, but I still get a 404:

```
from aiohttp.web_urldispatcher import SystemRoute

def middleware(f):
    f.__middleware_version__ = 1
    return f

def trailing_slashes():
    @middleware
    async def impl(request, handler):
        if isinstance(request.match_info.route, SystemRoute):
            rel_url = str(request.rel_url)
            if '?' in rel_url:
                path, query = rel_url.split('?', 1)
                query = f'?{query}'
            else:
                path = rel_url
                query = ''
            if not path.endswith('/'):
                rel_url = f'{path}/{query}'
                request = request.clone(rel_url=rel_url)

        return await handler(request)

    return impl
```

This is a class that implements the middleware and illustrates the problem.

```
from aiohttp import web
import slashes_mw

class ClassName(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = web.Application(middlewares=[slashes_mw.trailing_slashes()])
        self.app.add_routes(self.get_routes())
        web.run_app(self.app, port=80, host='0.0.0.0')

    def get_routes(self):
        return [
            web.get('/', self.handler),
            web.get('/{name}/', self.handler)
        ]

    def handler(self, request):
        return web.Response(text='hello')

ClassName()
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the redirect approach that they propose is quite correct, as the routes are simply not the same. But you might try to just register the second "version" of the route as well:

```
def get_routes(self):
    return [
        web.get('/', self.handler),
        web.get('/{name}/', self.handler),
        web.get('/{name}', self.handler)
    ]
```

This should handle your problem server-side (NOT TESTED).

As I understand the framework, your approach does not work because the specific handler is selected BEFORE the different middlewares are called. If you call the handler function in the middleware, there is no "routing" lookup done anymore. Or at least that is how I understand their documentation: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#middlewares

Might be interesting as well: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#variable-resources